# page scrolls to the top when clicking inside of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bigcommerce

i am iframing a bubble.is(rapid application development platform) application, when i click on a slider range inside of the iframe it scrolls the main(parent) page to the top. I don't have any scrolling or page moving functionality.

i have tried to block some of the hooks with jquery but i am not familiar enough with web design.

```
var iframeSource = 'example.com';
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.setAttribute('src', iframeSource);
    iframe.setAttribute('id', 'the_iframe');

    iframe.style.width = 1200 + 'px';
    iframe.style.height = 2000 + 'px';
 document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

so when i click on the slider i get this error message in the console:

[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952
when it jumps to the top